# Checking both ends of a string not working

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to the beginning of a string and the end. If the word has an uppercase letter we change it to lowercase. If the word has a space or `'"'` we erase the character. The first recursive call it should check and see that the end of the string has a capital letter and it should change it to lowercase. However when I output `word[word.size()]` it outputs a blank space, but it I output `word[word.size() - 1]` it will output the letter that I am looking for. I wasn't sure what the blank space is and how I should handle it as I don't want it in my string because it is causing comparison issues.

```
bool checkPalindrome(string word){
if (isupper(word[0]))
{
    word[0] = tolower(word[0]);
}

if (isupper(word[word.size()]))
{
    word[word.size()] = tolower(word[word.size()]);
}

//check if there is a space or "" if there is then delete that position from the string
if (word[0] == ' ' || word[0] == '"')
{
    word.erase(1);
}

if (word[word.size()] == ' ' || word[word.size()] == '"')
{
    word.pop_back();
}

if (word.size() > 1)
{
    if (word[0] == word[word.size()])
    {
        word = word.substr(1, word.size() - 2);
        return checkPalindrome(word, count);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
else
{
    return false;
}
int main()
{

    ifstream inFile;
    bool check = false;
    string temp = "";
    int count = 0;
    vector<string> vect;

    //Reading from a file line by line
    inFile.open("words.txt");
    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(inFile, temp))
        {
            vect.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    inFile.close();

    for (auto i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
    {
        count = vect[i].size();
        check = checkPalindrome(vect[1], count);

        if (check == true)
        {
            cout << vect[i] << ", is a palindrome!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << vect[i] << ", is not a palindrome.\n";
        }
    }
   } return 0;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. In this case, you may hardcoded content of `words.txt`.

Comment: `word[word.size()]` is one past the last letter. Valid indices are `[0 to size-1]`.

Comment: As of C++11, the easiest way to get the beginning and ending characters of a `string` is with the `front` and `back` methods. Test to ensure the string isn't empty first, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [off-by-one error with string functions (C/C++) and security potentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827016/off-by-one-error-with-string-functions-c-c-and-security-potentials)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp `word[word.size()]` is valid in C++11 and later, it returns a reference to the string's null terminator.

Comment: Thank you everyone this makes much more sense now

Comment: I figured it out, thank you everyone so much.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the string is 4, then there are only 4 elements: 0, 1, 2, and 3. There is no fifth element, so you cannot access element number four.

If a string's length is five:

Zero is the first element.
One is the second element.
Two is the third element.
Three is fourth element.

The fifth element is, of course Leeloo, which is not a character in the string. If a string's length is four, you should not attempt to access the fifth element (at least, not without her permission).

Ecto gamat.

Comment: "*There is no fifth element, so you cannot access element number four.*" - Actually, in C++11 and later, there is a fifth element, the null terminator, which you can legally access with `operator[]`.